# table.sort throws " invalid order function"

Tags: sorting, lua

I'm developing a simple friend system and want to sort the friendData with some 
rules.

I compared two friends' status , level and offline-Time.

PS:A friend has 3 status.(Online = 3,Busy = 2,Offline = 1).

Here's my code.

```
local function compare(friend1,friend2)
    local iScore1 = 0
    local iScore2 = 0
    if friend1["eStatus"] > friend2["eStatus"] then
        iScore1 = iScore1 + 1
    end
    if friend1["iLevel"] > friend2["iLevel"] then
        iScore1 = iScore1 + 1
    end
    if friend1["iOfflineTime"] < friend2["iOfflineTime"] then
        iScore1 = iScore1 + 1
    end
    return iScore1 > iScore2
end
table.sort(FriendData,compare)
```

It works when I add several friends.But when I get more friends,It throws exception "invalid order function for sorting".
Can someone please tell me how to fix it? :)

Comment: what happens if iScore1 = iScore2? What if any of these values are the same?

Comment: I expect that the function will return false if iScore1 == iScore2

Comment: Check out this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092502/lua-table-sort-claims-invalid-order-function-for-sorting

Comment: Order function is invalid because it is possible that both `compare(friend1,friend2)` and `compare(friend2,friend1)` return `true`.

Comment: Indeed. Thx for help.  ：）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Paul Hebert and @Egor Skriptunoff ,I Figure it out.

The key is that compare(a,b) and compare(b,a) should have different returned results.

That means:

1. When iScore1 == iScore2,there should be an unique value for comparing(e.g.,accountID).
2. Different compared value should have different scores.

Here is the new code.

```
local function compare(friend1,friend2)
    local iScore1 = 0
    local iScore2 = 0
    if friend1["eStatus"] > friend2["eStatus"] then
        iScore1 = iScore1 + 100
    elseif friend1["eStatus"] < friend2["eStatus"] then
        iScore2 = iScore2 + 100
    end
    if friend1["iLevel"] > friend2["iLevel"] then
        iScore1 = iScore1 + 10
    elseif friend1["iLevel"] < friend2["iLevel"] then
        iScore2 = iScore2 + 10
    end
    if friend1["iOfflineTime"] < friend2["iOfflineTime"] then
        iScore1 = iScore1 + 1
    elseif friend1["iOfflineTime"] > friend2["iOfflineTime"] then
        iScore2 = iScore2 + 1
    end
    if iScore1 == iScore2 then --They are both 0.
        return  friend1["accountID"] > friend2["accountID"]
    end
    return iScore1 > iScore2
end
table.sort(FriendData,compare)
```